# Apache's httpd.exe won't run on my Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, httpd

I went to apache.org and downloaded httpd server for my Windows7, after successful install, I try to run it and I get following message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version: 2.2.15.0
  Application Timestamp: 4b8fed95
  Fault Module Name: php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.3.2.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4b8ebac2
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000e6d2c
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I’m confused, what am I doing wrong, and/or how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, but FWIW, I've had good luck installing Apache on Windows as part of "XAMPP" (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)...

Answer (score 2):

I found a blog post that might help you 
http://farinspace.com/2010/02/php-error-faulting-module-name-php5ts/
Seems like your php installation might be the reason for your woes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it by right clicking on the exe and choosing run as administrator. You may be an admin on your PC, but you still that only grants you the right to run things as an admin.

Comment: i'll try when i get home tonight, but i ran this through services

Answer (score -1):

If Apache on Windows is similar to Apache on Linux, then you don't usually run it directly. Is there an apache2ctl.exe in the same directory as the httpd.exe?

Apache processes usually run as a specific Apache user (e.g. www-data on Mint 8) for security reasons.

Comment: while apache on Windows is very much alike to Apache on Linux, there are different ways of starting apache, on Linux its done through apachectl or init.d script on Windows it's done most commonly through services or through apache's monitor utility.